# Универсальные классы

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Столкнулся с проблемой и не знаю, как её красиво решить.

Есть класс Popup с конструктором, принимающем на вход некоторые параметры (это существенно). У класса Popup есть несколько потомков - OkPopup, ErrorPopup, etc.
Пользовательские классы (условно) выглядят так:

```
class BaseClient
{
}

class ClientA : BaseClient
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        // код
        string params = "123";
        Popup popup = new OkPopup(params);
        // код
    }
}

class ClientB : BaseClient
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        // тоже самый код, что и выше
        string params = "123";
        Popup popup = new ErrorPopup(params);
        // второй тоже самый код, что и выше
    }
}
```

На лицо копи-пейст кода, что есть грех и мракобесие. Как от этого избавиться?

Если бы конструктор класса Popup не получал параметров, то задача легко бы решалась при помощи шаблонов (универсальных классов):

```
class BaseClient<PopupType> where PopupType : new()
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        // код
        string params = "123";
        Popup popup = new PopupType();
        // код
    }
}

class ClientA : BaseClient<OkPopup>
{
}

class ClientB : BaseClient<ErrorPopup>
{
}
```

Но загвоздка именно в том, что конструктор должен принимать параметры. А в этом случае шаблоны уже не применимы (ограничения языка).

Есть ощущение, что здесь можно как-то правильно применить порождающие патерны проектирования. Например:

```
class BaseClient<PopupType> where PopupType : new()
{
    protected Popup Prototype;
    public void Foo()
    {
        // код
        string params = "123";
        Popup popup = (Popup) Prototype.Clone()
        // код
    }
}

class ClientA : BaseClient
{
    ClientA()
    {
        Prototype = new OkPopup();
    }
}

class ClientB : BaseClient
{
    ClientB()
    {
        Prototype = new ErrorPopup();
    }
}
```

Но такой код мне не очень нравится. 
Во-первых, потребуется усложнить структуру базового класса Popup, определив в нём операцию клонирования. Замена Прототипа на Фабрику не упростит ситуацию, а перераспределит сложность: класс Popup останется простым, но станет сложнее диаграмма классов. 
Во-вторых, чуть усложнится код клиентских классов. А хочется его упростить, а не усложнить.

Что можно сделать?

PS: в коде есть шероховатости, но не хотелось "вылизывать" демонстрационный код, дабы не "зашумлять" основную идею того или иного примера.

Comment: Паттерн "Шаблонный метод" почитай.

Answer (score 2):

Если иерархия пользовательских классов сделана только ради параметризации по `Popup` и если все наследники `Popup` конструируются с использованием одинакового набора параметров, то можно отказаться от параллельной иерархии:

```
class Client
{
    private readonly Func<string, Popup> _createPopupAction;

    public Client(Func<string, Popup> createPopupAction)
    {
        _createPopupAction = createPopupAction;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        // код
        string @params = "123";
        Popup popup = _createPopupAction(@params);
        // код
    }
}
```

Comment: Наследование сделано не ради параметризации по Popup: пользовательские классы являются тестовыми классами для некоторых иных классов. Но выглядит красиво.

Answer (score 0):

По совету @Алексей получается примерно такой код на основе Шаблонного Метода:

```
abstract class BaseClient
{
    protected abstract Popup GeneratePopup(string params);

    public void Foo()
    {
        // код
        string params = "123";
        Popup popup = GenaratePopup(params);
        // код
    }
}

class ClientA : BaseClient
{
    protected override Popup GeneratePopup(string params) 
    { 
        return new OkPopup(params); 
    }
}

class ClientB : BaseClient
{
    protected override Popup GeneratePopup(string params) 
    { 
        return new ErrorPopup(params); 
    }
}
```

Если есть ещё более изящные варианты, то буду рад.

Comment: Class в C# пишется с маленькой буквы. и BaseClient должен быть абстрактным. Код их вашего вопроса приходится дорабатывать напильником чтобы просто начать писать ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Шаблонный метод:

```
abstract class BaseClient
{
    protected abstract Popup CreatePopup();

    public void Foo()
    {
        // тоже самый код, что и выше
        Popup popup = this.CreatePopup();
        // второй тоже самый код, что и выше
    }
}

class ClientA : BaseClient
{
    protected override Popup CreatePopup()
    {
        string params = "123";
        return new OkPopup(params);
    }
}

class ClientB : BaseClient
{
    protected override Popup CreatePopup()
    {
        string params = "123";
        return new ErrorPopup(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если список параметров конструктора известен заранее и одинаков у разных потомков - то есть вот такой вариант (только тут бы еще обработку исключений добавить):

```
public static class ClientCreator {
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<params, T>> creators = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<params, BaseClient>>();

    private static Func<params, BaseClient> Make(Type type) {
         var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(params) });
         var ps = Expression.Parameter(typeof(params));
         return Expression.Lambda<Func<params, BaseClient>>(Expression.New(ctor, ps), ps).Compile();
    }

    public static BaseClient Create(params ps) {
        return creators.GetOrAdd(Make)(ps);
    }
}
```

В принципе, сюда несложно добавить и логику выбора между несколькими конструкторами, если надо. Но делать так следует только в очень простых случаях - как правило, использование шаблонного метода или фабрики дает более простой в понимании код.

С другой стороны, похожий подход можно использовать для генерации на лету нужной фабрики. Нечто подобное, только сложнее, делается в Autofac.